# Cost structure of creating a new database for high-frequency (streaming) data

Tags: mysql, database-design

First off my apology if this scenario & questioning reads as vague or general; I'll try to be as specific as possible, for the current stage of consideration:

- A desktop application is being designed for interaction (via streaming TCP/IP socket connection) with a remote server (with a C++ API) that supplies high-frequency (sub-second in some cases) data, which has eight parameters/values per timestamp. Data for four 'products' will be subscribed to in a continuous manner from 09:00-17:00ET M-F, and the same data format for twenty-six other products will be subscribed to during non-peak hours (20:00-21:00).
- In all cases, the data received will be saved to one MySQL table on the PC running this desktop application. The data will be queried later by several *basic* R and Python scripts for analysis, which for sake of consideration here, just means installing the packages that enable the connection (pymysql, etc), nothing further than that.
- In time, the volume of data may grow to 5-6 million 'rows' (each row containing values of the eight parameters) for each product, so 150-180 million rows total.

**The question is:** **What aspects of building/implementing such a database would be the most time-intensive for a programmer (complexity; sheer, eventual capacity req'd)?** I ask this from perspective of the end-user seeking to hire a programmer, and have received price quotes reaching well above $10k. It is established during the discussion with programmers that I will be hosting and maintaining the database, so cost concern is limited to design & build.

Comment: I would focus on data ingest in batches where batches are not initially inserted but rather housed and staged in recreate-able segments. I would also focus on a minimal Proof-of-Concept so that you choose the right solution provider

Comment: What did the $10k include? As you described it, it sounds pretty straightforward for someone with several years of experience. Aspects that would be most intensive for programmer implementing this would be queuing system that @Drew is referring to. You have many small queries. To make MySQL work fast, you want to write a lot of data at once. To do that you queue several queries and "flush" them at once to disk. You can also buy fast SSD's and ignore the queue system, hoping the disk can cope. This is about what I can contribute to this question. Good luck!

Comment: My mantra:  "Don't queue it, just do it."  30 direct inserts per second is not a problem.  Feeding them through a queue would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that programmers expect some extra communication during streaming setup and some performance optimization.

My estimate would be:

- stream analysis (communication PoC) - 3MD
- data analysis - 1MD
- project setup - 1MD
- initial database setup - 2MD
- coding - 3MD
- unit/integration tests - 2MD
- presentation of running code - 1MD
- performance optimization - 4MD
- performance tests - 2MD
- working code presentation - 1MD

So 20MD + 30% reserve = 27MD. With US salary of $400 per day you end up with $10.8k. In Europe you can get quotes like $250 per day, so around $6.5k or $7k.